# Breeze Changing the Order of ComplexType Classes

Tags: asp.net-web-api, breeze

I am trying to load a "ComplexType" property (p2) that is being called from a ComplexType property (p1) (Nested ComplexType). After getting the metadata I see that both classes were recognized as complextypes, but in breeze.debug

```
toArray(schema.complexType)
```

it's seeing the p1 (outside complextype) first, so then when it tries to resolve one of its property type which is a complexType, p2. it's reading

```
var type = typeMap[qualTypeName];
```

and since "typeMap" doesn't have p2 and "okNotFound" is false, it's throwing an error

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to locate an 'Type' by the name: Address:#Domain
```

Anyone have run into the same problem? Am I missing something very obvious? Is there a way I can tell EFContextProvider in MVC4 Web API to render p1 before p2 when creating Metadata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: This was a bug and as of v 1.3.2 has been fixed.

---

This may be a bug.  We have not tested extensively with nested complex types. I will try to confirm it today or tommorow.

Comment: Yes. Thank you for the fixing it. It's now verified in my case.