# Breeze with Nested ComplexTypes

Tags: breeze

I'm running into some problems with nested ComplexTypes. Not the exact same error as described in [Breeze Changing the Order of ComplexType Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774009/breeze-changing-the-order-of-complextype-classes) but that's probably because the nested ComplexType is also a property of some other model.

- Customer => Address
- Customer => InvoiceDetails => Address

The error i'm getting is a Javascript NullRefException on nextParent.complexType. This is in the ComplexAspect constructor. After debugging Breeze i believe this call should be nextParent.complexAspect.parent. But after changing that code i'm getting some other errors i haven't been able to debug into yet.

Has anyone else seen this problem with Breeze?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**: As of v 1.3.2, this is now fixed.  And... thanks for the repro! Please post back here if the issue has not been corrected.

---

I have been trying to repro this but...  Can you please send a copy of the json metadata returned by a *EntityManager.fetchMetadata* call to your service to breeze@ideablade.com ( attn: Jay Traband) and I'll try to repro/fix it.

Comment: I've mailed the json metadata and included a link to a sample repro project.

Comment: Got it, I will try to get to this later today and thx for the repro.

Comment: I've updated our solution with v 1.3.2 and it works perfectly! Thanks for the quick fix!!